# Syncronize Infinite Transition for colors in Android Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am creating a UI for Android using Kotlin, Jetpack Compose, and M3. I have the following composable function:

```
@Composable
fun BlinkingCards()
{
    val blinkAnimation = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    var isSecondCardBlinking by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val firstCardAnimColor by blinkAnimation.animateColor(
        initialValue = MaterTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
        targetValue = MistedYellow // 'Color' type defined in another file
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 1000,
                //easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )
    val secondCardAnimColor by blinkAnimation.animateColor(
        initialValue = Color.Transparent, // the second animation has a different initial val 
        targetValue = MistedYellow // 'Color' type defined in another file
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 1000,
                //easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        OutlinedCard(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = firstCardAnimColor ),
        ) {
            // content
        }
        OutlinedCard(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = if (isSecondCardBlinking) 
                secondCardAnimColor 
                else 
                Color.Transparent),
        ) {
            // content
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                // Trigger the button click event
                isSecondCardBlinking = true
            }
        ) {
            Text("Start Blinking")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

In this simple example, there is a rememberInfiniteTransition used to create two animated colors that are then used on the backgrounds of two OutlinedCards. To start, the first card is blinking by default between the secondary color defined by my MatertialTheme and the color MistedYellow. When the 'Start Blinking' button is clicked, the second card begins blinking between the transparent color to MistedYellow as well.

When this is viewed in app, the blinking of both the cards is independent of each other. The blinking behavior starts at different times. How might I make it so that both cards blink and change color together in sync?

I get the behavior I want if I use the same animated color on both card backgrounds, however this means that both cards will have the same initial and ending color values. How do I make it so that the cards blink together but with different card values?

I expected that using the same blinkAnimation to create both animated colors would allow animation to sync together. However this is not the case. The color of the cards blink separately.

I suspect a solution to this is to create a Box that fills the entirety of both cards. Each card would then have their own fixed color while the Box would blink between Color.Transparent and MistedYellow using the same animated color, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Thanks in advance.